# Difference between present perfect and past perfect?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

Can someone explain what past perfect is?

Consider:

When do I use past perfect? I know past perfect refers to a time in the past or the activity happened before and after the other activity. But sometimes, people use it and is not determined by the time or when the event occurred (before or after).

I can not understand. Please, explain for me.

Comment: We can't explain particular uses if you haven't given us examples of what those particular uses are. Please don't make us guess.

Comment: The present and past perfects are topics which fill whole chapters in grammar books. And grammar books such as Swan's _Practical English Usage_ are really the best places to go for answers to your question. Another point: the experts on this site are generally very keen to help, but they expect questioners to take a little care to proofread their questions before posting. Your text has several orthographic and spelling mistakes that can give a negative impression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but I will tell you about two English verb tenses.

"I **have read** your question." This sentence is in the present perfect. It means that I read your letter in the past, but I'm describing this fact as a fact about me now. The word "have" is an auxiliary verb in the present perfect.

"I **had read** your question when John entered the room." The first part of this sentence is in the past perfect. The sentence expresses that I read your question in the past, John entered the room in the past, and of those two events, the reading was earlier than the entering. Past perfect is a way of putting past events in chronological order. The word "had" is an auxiliary verb in the past perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition in traditional grammar books is that past tense verbs only indicates *a time in the past*. It is important to know the difference between the `grammatical` category of *a past tense* and the `semantic` property. This is in relation to your question:

> 'But sometimes, people use [tenses] and is not determined by the time or when the event occurred.'

Where the traditional definition **fails** (examples taken from Geoffrey and Pullum's "A student's introduction to English grammar"):

> i) I thought the course *started* next week. 
>  ii) If he *said* that, she wouldn't believe him 
> iii) I regret *offending* the Smiths.

In i) the past tense verb *started* (grammatical category) indicates a possible time in the future and not the past (semantic property)

In ii) the past tense verb *said* relies on the conditional "if", therefore if the condition [he said that] was met then [I wouldn't believe him]. The inference here is basically: She would believe it if anyone else said that, other than *him*.

It is not referring to the past but the possibility of it occurring in the past (if it is not within her knowledge), present (he said *that* as she talks about it but not within her consciousness) and future (if he happens to say it).

In iii) The present tense verb 'offending' is referring to the past (semantic property) but is used in the present tense form (grammatical category).

It is important to know the basics before you move onto present perfects and past perfects.

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect
**Use:** We use present perfect to talk about things that happened at an unspecified time in the past.  It's a completed action. When the action occurred is not relevant. The important thing is that it happened before now. It's commonly used to describe past experiences. 
 Present perfect sentence: I have seen that movie. Verb: have seen.
Past Perfect
**Use** We use the Past perfect to talk about two activities. One activity happens before the other, but both activities happened in the past.
Past perfect sentence: I didn't go because I had seen the movie already. Verb: had seen.

Comment: Hi. A present perfect doesn't signify that an action has necessarily been complete. The action can still continue onto the present e.g. I have been living in this house all my life. [X](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/)